# Got an error try to use live-server node.js

Tags: node.js, powershell

i got an error trying to run live-server,
[this is happen after changing the policy restriction in powershell to unrestricted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqwcO.png)

Comment: While someone may have run into this issue before, if you can provide additional context about the error you are experiencing, it would help us help you. Can you give details about the execution policy you set? What do you see from Get-ExecutionPolicy? Did live-server work before setting this policy? What content are you trying to serve?

Comment: i set Get-ExecutionPolicy from undefined to unrestricted, before changing to unrestricted i got an error in vs code:  live-server : File C:\Users\nadza\AppData\Roaming\npm\live-server.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on 
this system. after change it to Unrestricted it become like in the picture

Comment: Are you trying to serve an HTML page? If so, can you show the file content? Have you tried closing the terminal and opening it again?

Comment: yup i tried to serve an HTML page,its a basic html with just linking my script.js, i tried to close the terminal and try to open again, and that happen again

Answer (score 0):

Just to let you know, I found an answer to this problem from a [different post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70656184/how-can-i-solve-node-js-live-sever-install-error). It looks like one of the dependent packages has been sabotaged. This will likely be fixed in a few days.